# iphone global var goes null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, global-variables

I have a globals.h and my appdelegate.h and m.

In the globals.h I have:

```
extern NSString  *databasePath;
```

in appdelegate.h I have

```
NSString *databasePath;
```

in appdelegate.m I assign a value and print it:

```
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

NSLog(@"Database is:%@", databasePath);
```

All is good up to this point.  When I call another class and display the data the same way the databasePath is gone.

However if I make assign databasePath like this, then it works and I am able to use NSLog to show the value:

```
databasePath =@"XYZZY";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `When I call another class ...` Do you mean another method declared in the same interface as part of **appdelegate.h** ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, so I'm going to give you two answers here. You might want to clarify your question. :)

### C globals don't work that way.

Others seem to be making the assumption that you have the `NSString *database` in your class. But I'm going to take your question at face value and assume you have it loose in appdelegate.h.

(Incidentally, that makes this a C problem, not an Objective-C one.)

What's happening is that each time appdelegate.h is being imported, the .m file ultimately responsible for the import is getting a new copy of it.

You should have `extern` in appdelegate.h as well. The non-extern `NSString *database` must be in a .m file.

### Objective-C doesn't work that way.

The other possibility is, of course, that you really do have `NSString *database` in your class. That makes it not a global variable, but an instance variable. You can't declare it as a global by using `extern NSString *database` in another header. What you're doing, then, is setting the instance variable in your AppDelegate and accessing a same-named global from your other class.

Remove the global entirely and just use your AppDelegate. You can read it using an accessor.

Something like:

```
id appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplicaiton] delegate];
id databasePath = [appDelegate databasePath];
```

Comment: Good point in the first section. I haven't noticed that variable is defined in a header file. This fact makes my answer inadequate :)

Answer (score 1):

`[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName]` returns an unowned string. It will have been wiped from memory before you try to use it later. In general case, this could cause an EXC_BAD_ACCESS type of crash.
If you'd like to use the string at a later time, `copy` or `retain` it to get ownership over it. You may want to release it in the app delegate's `dealloc` method (or before assigning another value to your global var).

In the case with `@"XYZZY"`, you're using a constant string literal which persists in memory for the whole app lifetime. That's why it works as expected.

Comment: How do you copy it?  Sorry I am still learning this stuff. As its a NSString I cant just make String1 = String2 I assume?

Comment: @Mark Worsnop `String1 = String2` is just a pointer assignment. What you need copied is the object pointed to. This can be done like so: `String1 = [String2 copy]`. Another option is to use `retain` (because not every class implements a copy method, but every object has `retain` method). This is done similarly to copying: `String1 = [String2 retain]`.